# Time in setTimeout and behavior with page load event

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

I would like to improve my page performance. So I decided to load asynchronously a very slow script.
I'm using setTimeout to not block load event:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON('../api/orbit/banner', function(d){
        if (d && d.token && d.url) $.getScript(d.url + '?key=' + d.token);
    });
}, 150);
```

[image: with 0.15 seconds]

I realize that even with setTimeout, my page load time doesn't change, but with I put a greater time in setTimeout, like 2 seconds, all is gone fine but script load is more slow than before.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON('../api/orbit/banner', function(d){
        if (d && d.token && d.url) $.getScript(d.url + '?key=' + d.token);
    });
}, 2000);
```

[image: With 2 seconds]

Tested in Chrome and Firefox, same behavior.

Why? ‍♂️

Comment: Are you looking at the DOMContentLoaded and wondering why it has increased, because the script load is clearly better.

Comment: Async requests (such as those made by `$.getJSON()`) **never** block the page load

Comment: Vanilla JS is faster than jQuery...  in everything, and even  in a fetch

Comment: @Bibberty No, I looking at Load time.

Comment: @Phil I think so, but load time is greater with only 150 miliseconds.

Comment: @MrJ I agree, but is a big portal that already uses jQuery for inumerous features, I just took advantage.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/